# C++/CLI - Reading from a variable which is being written to

Tags: c++-cli

If I use BackgroundWorker to create two threads, and one thread is writing to a static member variable of a class while the other is reading, does this cause the application to crash?

If no, how does C++/CLI handle it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not cause the application to crash per-se. It causes undefined behavior. Which means, more or less, *anything* can happen.

What you're talking about is a race condition. These are bad; your main job when writing multithreaded code is to prevent these from happening.

Comment: So C++/CLI doesn't deal with this itself? It's up to the developer? Thanks!